# What kind of authentication does the Twitter API require or use at the moment?

Tags: oauth, twitter

I'm having a hard time figuring out how Twitter API authentication works. I want to make a simple Twitter utility that runs on the Mac and have heard from various sources that Twitter changed it's authentication model several times.

Is it still OAuth or did Twitter change this again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still [OAuth 1.0a](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849). To see more, check https://dev.twitter.com/docs, at the very bottom, under "Authentication".

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of a Cocoa demo or open source project that makes use of Twitter's API with OAuth?

Comment: Not exactly, no. But you can look up for any decent project in this list:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/open-source-examples

Comment: At the moment it is OAuth 1.1